# How to force the page to always scroll to bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using angular js to build a chat app. The problem is when the page loads or a new chat comes in, it doesn't properly scroll to the bottom of the page. This is the code that handles the scroll to bottom of page

```
var app = angular.module('chatApp', ['ui.bootstrap','mwl.confirm']);
app.directive('myRepeatDirective', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last) {
      document.getElementById("main-container").scrollTo(0, document.getElementById("main-container").scrollHeight);
    }
     };
  })
```

Here `#main-container` is the entire chat box in which chat happens.
Now I found some solutions on the web and this one seems to kind of work.

```
var app = angular.module('chatApp', ['ui.bootstrap','mwl.confirm']);
app.directive('myRepeatDirective', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last) {
      var objDiv = document.getElementById("main-container");
      objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    }
     };
  })
```

But the problem is some chat may have a link which opens up in the card. So after implementing this solution, when I refresh the page, it does scrolls to the bottom but as soon as it encounters a card with html link which opens up, it stops scrolling down and stops there.

Is there a way to force the page to scroll to bottom or maybe a timer which would scroll to bottom every other second. (Not sure if this is a good solution)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already binding to a chat message collection inside your template, you can simply craft a directive which watches for changes to that collection in order to immediately perform scroll adjustments. This way, you avoid having an arbitrary interval between scroll adjustments.

Here's a distilled example of how you might go about this:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.messages = [];
    // Simulate new chat messages being appended
    $interval(() => $scope.messages.push(Date.now()), 1000);
  })
  .directive('autoScrollBottom', function () {
    return function (scope, el, attrs) {
      scope.$watchCollection(attrs.autoScrollBottom, function () {
        el[0].scrollTop = el[0].scrollHeight;
      });
    };
  });
```

```css
.chat {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="chat" auto-scroll-bottom="messages">
    <div ng-repeat="m in messages">{{m}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular@1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive for this:

```
.directive('scrollDown', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
     scrollDown: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.$watchCollection('scrollDown', function (newValue) {
        if (newValue)
        {
          $(element).scrollTop($(element)[0].scrollHeight);
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```